# Proteins, ProteinData, WolframAlpha

Tags: curated-data, wolfram-alpha-queries, chemistry

> Apologies in advance, this is the first I've messed with `ProteinData` and access through `WolframAlpha`, so clearly I may not know how *Mathematica* and *Alpha* decide on what is the 'right way' to ask for things of this ilk.

I'd like to grab `ProteinData[]`, specifically a 3D model of the `"RibbonStructure"`, of *rhodopsin*.

I can easily get a low-resolution, static image from Alpha, directly in *Mathematica*:

[image: Alpha pod]

but I'd prefer the manipulatable 3D sort one gets from `ProteinData[]`, since this is much better for classroom demos, interactive explanation, etc.

[image: ribbon model of A2M]

So, I try to look up *rhodopsin* via `ProteinData` in a wide variety of ways, by name, by PDB name, nada-

[image: attempts]

Let's try an alias ---

[image: ProteinData works]

Success! But, there is no `MoleculePlot`

[image: missing MoleculePlot]

It knows a few things about "RHO", but not the things I need; and, more importantly, what Alpha is able to return.

So I'm at a loss here. I've tried other aliases ("OPN2", "visual purple") to no avail. I'm curious about ---

- Is there any way to figure out what `WolframAlpha` is doing with my request, since it can clearly interpret `rhodopsin` or `rhodopsin protein`?
- Is there a better way to use `ProteinData` than just randomly trying things? Is there a mapping somewhere of PDB <-> aliases, etc?
- Is there a way to as Alpha to return a higher resolution image than the sort-of-lame 320× I get? I know how to ask for just that pod, but it's unclear if there are any ways of asking for better / different pod content.

Comment: When you click the subpod containing the low-res image and then right click to paste the computable WolframAlpha call you see that even this doesn't work.

Comment: The typical way to find entities is to use inline free-form input. For example "AAMP protein" gives you an entity for that protein if you search for it in this way. Free-form search for "rhodopsin protein" does not give you an entity, which suggests to me that it doesn't exist.

Comment: yet, "RHO" exists, which is rhodopsin... so lord knows what it's thinking.

Comment: @halirutan - yeah- I forgot to mention that too. Intuition = fails. I now have a notebook called `Finding Rhodopsin` full of frustration :)

Comment: Looking at the paclet, it seems you are only going to get a "MoleculePlot" if the entity has a "PrimaryPDBID" property.  For instance, `ProteinData["RHOA", "MoleculePlot"]` works because `ProteinData["RHOA", "PrimaryPDBID"]`.  For now you'll have to use halirutan's workaround, but I would like to fix this soon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a workaround that directly queries the [PDB search API](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/software/rest.do) and returns the first `num` search results as a `Dataset[]`. The routine is more complicated than I'd like, due to the finicky nature of the API (it only takes queries in XML format), as well as the somewhat clunky way XML is represented in *Mathematica*:

```
pdbFindMoleculeName[name_String, num : (_Integer?Positive) : 10] := 
   Module[{query, res},
          query = XMLObject["Document"][{
                  XMLObject["Declaration"]["Version" -> "1.0", "Encoding" -> "UTF-8"]},
                  XMLElement["orgPdbQuery", {},
                  {XMLElement["queryType", {}, {"org.pdb.query.simple.StructTitleQuery"}],
                   XMLElement["struct.title.comparator", {}, {"contains"}],
                   XMLElement["struct.title.value", {}, {name}]}], {}];

          res = URLRead[HTTPRequest["http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/rest/search/",
                <|"ContentType" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
                  "Body" -> ExportString[query, "XML"], "Method" -> "POST"|>]];

          If[! FailureQ[res], res = Import[res];
             If[res =!= "null", res = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[res]];
                res = Dataset[AssociationThread[{"PDB ID", "Title", "Structure"},
                {#, Cases[Import["http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/rest/describePDB?structureId=" <>
                                 #, "XML"], ("title" -> t_) :> t, ∞][[1]], 

                 Import["https://files.rcsb.org/download/" <> # <> ".pdb", "PDB"]}] & /@
                Take[res, UpTo[num]]],
                res = Failure["NoResults",
                <|"MessageTemplate" :> "No results found for `name`", 
                  "MessageParameters" -> <|"name" -> name|>|>]]];
          res]
```

As a demo:

```
rhod = pdbFindMoleculeName["bovine rhodopsin"]
```

[image: Dataset for bovine rhodopsin]

Of course, the `Dataset[]` format allows for convenient querying; e.g., if you want to see the structure of [1HZX](http://dx.doi.org/10.2210/pdb1hzx/pdb):

```
First[rhod[Select[#"PDB ID" === "1HZX" &], "Structure"]]
```

[image: 1HZX structure]

Comment: I, for one, applaud our API using overlords.

Answer (score 8):

A quick and dirty is to download the PDB file from the main PDB database (eg
[Bovine rhodopsin](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/jmol.do?structureId=1U19&bionumber=1)), use the Download button/dropdown on the top right and select Text format
then

```
rhodopsin= Import["DownloadedFileAndPath","Rendering"->"Structure"]
```

Naturally, you could get Mathematica to do the download too.

Options for alternate renderings can be found in the [documentation for PDB format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/PDB.html)

Comment: What? You beat me by 5min.. Haven't seen your answer :( Get my upvote as you were clearly faster.

Comment: guys guys--- we're _all_ winners here.

Answer (score 8):

Try this here

```
Import["http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=pdb&compression=NO&structureId=1U19", "PDB"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Cheating :) ! But seriously, this is the way I've done it up until now, I was sort of hoping to use more of the nice builtin stuff, but I see it's rather incomplete.